# How do we visualize the pre-calculated quantile buckets in Grafana?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, eclipse-microprofile-config

I have an histogram type metrics which has pre-calculated quantile as mentioned below. Most of the prometheus examples are based on `_bucket` with label `le`, while the values fall into specific buckets.

```
# TYPE operation_duration_mean gauge
operation_duration_mean 0
# TYPE operation_duration_max gauge
operation_duration_max 0
# TYPE operation_duration_min gauge
operation_duration_min 0
# TYPE operation_duration_stddev gauge
operation_duration_stddev 0
# TYPE operation_duration summary
# HELP operation_duration 
operation_duration_count 0
operation_duration{quantile="0.5"} 0
operation_duration{quantile="0.75"} 0
operation_duration{quantile="0.95"} 0
operation_duration{quantile="0.98"} 0
operation_duration{quantile="0.99"} 0
operation_duration{quantile="0.999"} 0
```

Could not find any specific example for this to visualise it with `quantile`. Is there any standard way or example to refer on this ?

Thanks